# Implementing content provider, getting an error on retrieval of data: Failed to read row 0 column -1

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

While implementing content provider, I am getting an error on retrieval of data "saying: Failed to read row 0 column -1 from a cursor window".  My code, main activity, and error log are below.

```
package com.example.contentprovider;

import java.util.HashMap;



public class StudentsProvider extends ContentProvider{

    static final String PROVIDER_NAME="com.example.contentprovider";
    static final String URL="content://" + PROVIDER_NAME + "/students";
    static final Uri CONTENT_URI=Uri.parse(URL);

    static final String _ID="id";
    static final String NAME="name";
    static final String GRADE="grade";

    private static HashMap<String,String>STUDENTS_PROJECTION_MAP;
    static final int STUDENTS=1;
    static final int STUDENT_ID=2;

    static final UriMatcher uriMatcher;
    static{
        uriMatcher=new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
        uriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER_NAME, "students", STUDENTS);
        uriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER_NAME, "students/#", STUDENT_ID);
    }

    //Database specific constant declarations

    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    static final String DATABASE_NAME="College";
    static final String STUDENTS_TABLE_NAME="students";
    static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;
    static final String CREATE_DB_TABLE=" CREATE TABLE " + STUDENTS_TABLE_NAME +
              " (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + 
              " name TEXT NOT NULL, " +
              " grade TEXT NOT NULL);";

    // Helper class that actually creates and manages the providers underlying data
        //repository

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {

        public DatabaseHelper(Context context)
        {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL(CREATE_DB_TABLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ STUDENTS_TABLE_NAME);
            onCreate(db);
        }

    }

    public boolean onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Context context=getContext();
        DatabaseHelper dbHelper=new DatabaseHelper(context);
        /*
           Create a write able database which will trigger its 
           creation if it doesn't already exist.
         */
        db=dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return (db==null)?false:true;
    }


    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
        //Adding a new student record
        long rowID =db.insert(STUDENTS_TABLE_NAME, "", values);
        //If record is added successfully
        if(rowID>0)
        {
            Uri _uri=ContentUris.withAppendedId(CONTENT_URI, rowID);
            getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(_uri, null);
            return _uri;
        }
        throw new SQLException("Failed to add a record info " +uri);
    }


    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
            String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {

        SQLiteQueryBuilder qb=new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        qb.setTables(STUDENTS_TABLE_NAME);

        switch(uriMatcher.match(uri))
        {
        case STUDENTS:
            qb.setProjectionMap(STUDENTS_PROJECTION_MAP);
            break;
        case STUDENT_ID:
            qb.appendWhere(_ID+ "=" + uri.getPathSegments().get(1));
            break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI "+uri);
        }
        if(sortOrder==null || sortOrder=="")
        {
            sortOrder=NAME;
        }
        Cursor c=qb.query(db, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);

        //register to watch a content URI for changes
        c.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
        return c;
    }


    public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
          int count = 0;

          switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)){
          case STUDENTS:
             count = db.delete(STUDENTS_TABLE_NAME, selection, selectionArgs);
             break;
          case STUDENT_ID:
             String id = uri.getPathSegments().get(1);
             count = db.delete( STUDENTS_TABLE_NAME, _ID +  " = " + id + 
                    (!TextUtils.isEmpty(selection) ? " AND (" + 
                    selection + ')' : ""), selectionArgs);
             break;
          default: 
             throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI " + uri);
          }

          getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
          return count;
       }



    @Override
       public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, 
                         String[] selectionArgs) {
          int count = 0;

          switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)){
          case STUDENTS:
             count = db.update(STUDENTS_TABLE_NAME, values, 
                     selection, selectionArgs);
             break;
          case STUDENT_ID:
             count = db.update(STUDENTS_TABLE_NAME, values, _ID + 
                     " = " + uri.getPathSegments().get(1) + 
                     (!TextUtils.isEmpty(selection) ? " AND (" +
                     selection + ')' : ""), selectionArgs);
             break;
          default: 
             throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI " + uri );
          }
          getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
          return count;
       }

    @Override
    public String getType(Uri uri) {
        switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)){

           //Get all student records 

          case STUDENTS:
             return "vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd.example.students";

          // Get a particular student

          case STUDENT_ID:
             return "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.example.students";
          default:
             throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported URI: " + uri);
          }
    }


}
```

Main Activity....

```
   public void onClickRetrieveStudents(View view) 
            { //Retrieving Students Records String URL="content://com.example.contentprovider/students"; 
        Uri students=Uri.parse(URL);
         Cursor c=managedQuery(students, null, null, null, "name"); 
        if(c.moveToFirst()) 
        { 
    do{ Toast.makeText(this, c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(StudentsProvider._ID)) + ", "+ c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(StudentsProvider.NAME)) + ", "+ c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(StudentsProvider.GRADE)), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); } while(c.moveToNext()); } 
    }
```

Error log:

> 10-25 01:00:15.523: I/Choreographer(826): Skipped 93 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>    10-25 01:00:20.083: D/dalvikvm(826): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 226K, 13% free 2794K/3180K, paused 45ms, total 61ms 10-25 01:00:29.954: E/CursorWindow(826): Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 5 rows, 3 columns.
>    10-25 01:00:29.992: D/AndroidRuntime(826): Shutting down VM 10-25 01:00:29.992: W/dalvikvm(826): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)

Comment: the main activity is:public void onClickRetrieveStudents(View view)
 {
  //Retrieving Students Records
  String URL="content://com.example.contentprovider/students";
  Uri students=Uri.parse(URL);
  Cursor c=managedQuery(students, null, null, null, "name");
  if(c.moveToFirst())
  {
   do{
    Toast.makeText(this, c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(StudentsProvider._ID))
      + ", "+ c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(StudentsProvider.NAME))
      + ", "+ c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(StudentsProvider.GRADE)), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
   while(c.moveToNext());
  }
 }

Comment: post your error log cat

Comment: 10-25 01:00:15.523: I/Choreographer(826): Skipped 93 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-25 01:00:20.083: D/dalvikvm(826): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 226K, 13% free 2794K/3180K, paused 45ms, total 61ms
10-25 01:00:29.954: E/CursorWindow(826): Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 5 rows, 3 columns.
10-25 01:00:29.992: D/AndroidRuntime(826): Shutting down VM
10-25 01:00:29.992: W/dalvikvm(826): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)

Answer (score 1):

You made a mistake while initializing ID variable:

```
 static final String _ID="id";    // it must be "_id" value
```

Because you have created table with field name _id. `//_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT`

Comment: Thanks Paresh Mayani now i got it..can you please tell me what is use of setProjectionMap() in android.

Comment: @Dexter `setProjectionMap()` is used to set the projection map for the query. Here Projection means which data (columns) you would want to fetch from table. For example, Select Name, Address from Student;